# Angular $http 404 error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ajax, express

I'm receiving a 404 error when trying to send a post request and I'm not sure why. Also getting a 'possibly unhandled rejection' error. I'm quite new to Angular so any tips would be appreciated. I've looked over the documentation and found a variety of other information surrounding the structure of $http.post requests, but so far I can't apply it to what I'm trying to do here:

ng-click from my html file:

```
<button ng-click="addToFavorites(searchResults.response.data)" class="btn btn-success" type="button" name="addToFavorites">Add to Favorites</button>
```

Method call in my JS file

```
addToFavorites: function(movie) {
          var newMovie = isNewMovie(movie); // verify if movie has already been favorited
          if (newMovie) { // add to favoriteMovies if it's a new movie
            console.log(movie);
            // favoriteMovies.push(movie);
            $http.post('/m', movie).then(function(response) {
              console.log(response.data);
            });
            // .then(function(response) {
            //   console.log(response);
            // }).catch(function(err) {
            //   console.log('error:', err);
            // });
          } else { // alert user if it's already been favorited
            alert('This movie is already in your list of favorites.');
          }
        } // end addToFavorites()
```

Full JS file:

```
var pmdbApp = angular.module('pmdbApp', []);

pmdbApp.controller('InputController', ['$scope', 'MovieService', function($scope, MovieService) {
  console.log('InputController loaded');
  $scope.title = ''; // data-bound to user input field
  // $scope.searchForm = MovieService.searchForm;
  $scope.searchOMDB = MovieService.searchOMDB; // data-bound to user button click
  // reference to searchResults object
  // object contains the OMDB response as a property
  $scope.searchResults = MovieService.searchResults;
  $scope.getPoster = MovieService.getPoster; // bound to 'Search OMDB' button
  $scope.addToFavorites = MovieService.addToFavorites; // bound to 'Add to Favorites' button
}]); // end 'InputController'

pmdbApp.controller('OutputController', ['$scope', 'MovieService', function($scope, MovieService) {
  console.log('OutputController loaded');
  $scope.movieService = MovieService;
}]); // end 'OutputController'

pmdbApp.factory('MovieService', ['$http', function($http) {
  // searchResults object will be used to store response from the OMDB API
  var searchResults = {};
  /*var searchForm = {
    title: '',
    searchResults: {}
  };*/
  var favoriteMovies = [];

  function isNewMovie(movie) {
    for (var i = 0; i < favoriteMovies.length; i++) {
      if (movie.imdbID === favoriteMovies[i].imdbID) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  // var saveToDatabase = function(movie) {
  //   console.log('got here with movie', movie);
  //   $http.post('/movies', movie).then(function(response) {
  //     console.log('response');
  //   });
  // }

  // public information
  return {
    favoriteMovies: favoriteMovies,
    searchResults: searchResults, // pass an object referece
    // searchForm: searchForm,
    searchOMDB: function(title) {
      $http.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=' + title).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.data.Error) { // alert user if no movie matches search results
          alert('Movie not found!');
        } else { // otherwise store response as an object property
          searchResults.response = response;
        }
      }); // end $http.get
    }, // end searchOMDB()
    addToFavorites: function(movie) {
      var newMovie = isNewMovie(movie); // verify if movie has already been favorited
      if (newMovie) { // add to favoriteMovies if it's a new movie
        console.log(movie);
        // favoriteMovies.push(movie);
        $http.post('/m', movie).then(function(response) {
          console.log(response.data);
        });
        // .then(function(response) {
        //   console.log(response);
        // }).catch(function(err) {
        //   console.log('error:', err);
        // });
      } else { // alert user if it's already been favorited
        alert('This movie is already in your list of favorites.');
      }
    } // end addToFavorites()
  }; // end return
}]); // end 'MovieService'
```

Comment: Whenever I get a 404, it all goes clear using Chrome's network debug tab. Your server's log could also be of help, if you have it available.

Comment: 404 mean that the url you're requesting does not exist.

Comment: As mentioned above the URL doesn't exist or may be you are trying with the incorrect URL. Check if the URL is available by hitting the complete URL in any browser or any http client tool. It will help you to determine the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it was an error with how I was using Angular, but really it was simply an error in the route setup.

Client post:

```
    $http.post('/movies', movie).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.data);
    });
```

In my main server file:

```
app.use('/movies', movies);
```

In my router I HAD:

```
router.post('/movies', function(req, res) {
  console.log('/movies route hit with movie:', req.body);
  res.send('work, please');
});
```

When I should have just ' / ' in the router post. Of course the '/movies/movies' route does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a injection issue, can you make sure that you've injected all your dependency files to your application/controller?